# Automaticly fill in text after username in login box

Tags: html

I'm searching for an option to fill in something automaticly after a username in the login box like: perry@test

So @test should be always there after your username.

This is what we use right now.

Comment: Please edit the post and show your efforts to solve this yourself - what did you try to do so far?

Comment: I don't think HTML alone does the trick ... Anyway, the SO community is not there to provide a free coding service... Please read [How to ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot automatically append the value on an input box with HTML alone, you need Javascript.

If you use jquery, you can just append the text inside the input box when the value inside the input box is changed.

```
$( "#input" ).change(function() {
  $('#input').val($('#input').val() + '@test.com');
});
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/Washable/pen/JOLPJK

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion

Divide input box into columns and left column is actual input box where user can enter the username and right column can be a default text which holds the text @test

else you have to get to know when the user is done entering the username and then you can append the @test for that text(using javascript, jquery or angularjs etc).